# Render Twig without controller

Tags: controller, twig

Hello I want to render a template without controller. I define the route in routing.yml:

```
form:
path: /form/
defaults:
    _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
    template: 'TechappStatsBundle:Stats:form.html.twig'
```

And in my twig:

```
    <button href="{{ path('form') }}" class="btn btn-info btn-lg pull-right">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Ajouter un bloc 
    </button>
```

But when I click, I have "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "form" as such route does not exist.")"

Thanks for your help =)

Comment: Looks like and indentation problem

Comment: where? in my twig path and default are correct

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your route is not well defined in the YAML file. Change its definition by the following:

```
form:
    path: /form/
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template: 'TechappStatsBundle:Stats:form.html.twig'
```

Please note that YAML files require an strict indentation based on four white spaces.

Comment: yes i know but i think the problem is in the twig file

Comment: The Twig syntax that you showed (`{{ path('form') }}`) looks correct. If the route is "not defined" it's because it's not loaded by the application. Execute the `php app/console router:debug` command to list all the registered routes.

Comment: whene i execute  `php app/console router:debug`  i don't have the route for form

Comment: The reason is that the route is not correctly loaded in the application. You probabñy defined it in a file which is not loaded by the application.